# AJAX doesn't work on https

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Since i'm using https on my webserver, AJAX with an auto-refresh function of a div doesn't work. When I'm using HTTP, everything works fine. Can someone help me?

Here's the code which I'm using:

```
<b> 
    <div id="showMessages">
        <script src=http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
            function autoRefresh_div() {
                $("#showMessages").load("showMessages.php"); // a function which will load data from other file after x seconds
                alert("Auto-Refresh works fine"); 
            }

            setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 5000); // refresh div after 5 secs
        </script>
        <?php include("showMessages.php"); ?>
    </div>
</b><br>
```

The div is also available. Thanks to everybody

Comment: I don't see how this works anywhere given that you've put your JS code in a `script` tag with a `src` attribute. You need to use two separate `<script>` tags. Also note that you should put your JS includes and code either within the `<head>` or just before `</body>`. It should not be dumped in the middle of your markup. Finally, AJAX polling is not a good idea. With a few users on the site you're basically DDOSing yourself. Look in to use websockets instead

Comment: Also you forgot to put `"` in `src=http://ajax.googleapis.com/.....` before `http`. it should be `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $("#showMessages").load('showMessages.php')
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```